# bosh upload release invalid domain name

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-bosh, bosh-deployer

I am new to Cloud Foundry: I am uploading release to bosh director `vm` but it gets failed at this point:

```
 Started creating new packages > nodejs-buildpack/8a59261cda360607b665bdf4bf93f25e0edb7352. Failed: Failed to upload blob, code 1, output: 'Error running app - Putting dav blob 867f8098-fef6-453c-86a0-fa7f70ee1e5c: Put http://["192.168.1.2"]:25250/01/867f8098-fef6-453c-86a0-fa7f70ee1e5c: dial tcp: lookup "192.168.1.2": invalid domain name', error: '' (00:00:01)

Error 100: Failed to upload blob, code 1, output: 'Error running app - Putting dav blob 867f8098-fef6-453c-86a0-fa7f70ee1e5c: Put http://["192.168.1.2"]:25250/01/867f8098-fef6-453c-86a0-fa7f70ee1e5c: dial tcp: lookup "192.168.1.2": invalid domain name', error: ''
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing when you get this error? Which commands have you run? Which versions of BOSH and Cloud Foundry are you using? Is this on BOSH Lite, or a 'regular' BOSH?

Answer (score 2):

It *looks* like when you're uploading your release to the BOSH Director, the director is unable to contact the blobstore that's been configured (192.168.1.2).